# CMake find function defined in sibling path in project

Tags: cmake

CMake project structure:

- /project/CMakeLists.txt
- /project/lib/CMakeLists.txt
- /project/app/CMakeLists.txt

`/project/lib/CMakeLists.txt` defines a function

```
FUNCTION (LIB_MYFUNC ...)
    ...
ENDFUNCTION ()
```

The trouble is that `/project/app/CMakeLists.txt` can't see this function. It can see the function if the function lives in `/project/CMakeLists.txt` but that's not a sensible organization for my project because reasons.

For third party packages, functions are defined somewhere in the system installation and the project can `FIND_PACKAGE`. I do *not* want to have to define and install my library CMake stuff on the system, I want it all contained within the local project file tree.

How can I tell `/project/app/CMakeLists.txt` to search in sibling branches of the project for functions? (I don't want `/project/app/CMakeLists.txt` to have to know and name `/project/lib` explicitly, but for all sibling branches to be searched.)

Comment: "How can I tell `/project/app/CMakeLists.txt` to search in sibling branches of the project for functions?" - This question has no sense. CMake does NOT search functions in files. During parsing the files (top-level `CMakeLists.txt` and files included via `add_subdirectory`, `include` or `find_package`, if CMake encounters `FUNCTION()` command in it, then the name of the function becomes known for CMake. So further code is able to call this function. Note also, that functions in CMake are **global**, so even the function is defined in sub-`CMakeLists.txt`, it is accessible at top-level.

Comment: @Tsyvarev well that's not true because if a function is defined in `/project/lib` it cannot be used in `/project/app` so clearly there's some sort of scoping going on.

Comment: Please, show more of your code, preferable in form of [mcve]. It seems you do wrong things but do not describe then. E.g. `/project/lib/CMakeLists.txt` is actually not processed by CMake in your case.